# How to create view and action for item automatically?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a recipe web application. An user creates a recipe and the web application is putting this recipe to database. I am showing this recipes through foreach cycle at main page:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
 <div id="anItem">
     <div id="imgText"><img align="left" src="../../Content/Images/eggs.png" height="150" width="90"></div>
    <div id="text">@item.Text</div>
 </div>                     
}
```

However, it is not convenient as it is just big list of many recipes. What I want is to have an individual page per recipe.

So when user creates a recipe then some page(or action?) should be created. However, I could not figured out how to create an action method and its view automatically.

Maybe is there some mechanism to create views and actions automatically?

My question is:
 **How to create a view and its action method when a user creates(add) new item(recipe) to my database.** 
Also I want to have a link to the recipe.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your view becomes a generic "recipe," and you create a controller which has an `ID` that renders that generic recipe for the specific recipe as you pass it in. You only want one view, not one per recipe.

Comment: @EricHotinger, could you share with some links or examples. Thank you in adnvace!:)

Comment: I've given you a basic example as an answer below. You can customize it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a brief example of how to scaffold a generic model to create the overarching view page of all recipes, editing the details of a specific one, viewing them as a standalone, and deleting them using a brand new MVC 5 project.

First, create a `Recipe` in your `Models` folder. Make sure you add in the reference for Data Annotations so that Entity Framework knows your Primary Key for the object.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace RecipeSite.Models
{
    public class Recipe
    {
        [Key]
        public int Identifier { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now build your project. If you don't build your project and try to scaffold beforehand, the dlls will be out of sync and the scaffold may fail.

Next, scaffold out the controller and views. In Visual Studio, you can right click the Controllers folder and go to `Add -> Controller -> MVC 5 Controller with views using Entity Framework` Choose your `Recipe` model and the default `ApplicationDbContext` Name your Controller `RecipesController`

This is all you have to do to have a fully functional CRUD application for recipes to manage their names and descriptions.

So that's how you would automatically generate the functionality you desire. To further answer your original question, you can take a look at how the `Details` action on the `RecipesController` is implemented.

The generated code is as follows:

```
// GET: Recipes/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Recipe recipe = db.Recipes.Find(id);
    if (recipe == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(recipe);
}
```

As you can see, whenever you click on a `Recipe`'s link, it will pass in its `ID` to the controller, look it up from the database, and find it if possible. Then it will display the `Details.cshtml` page within the `Views` folder based on that ID.